# Clustered standard errors and robust standard errors

Tags: clustered-standard-errors, pooling, robust-standard-error

I was wondering if, when running a regression on panel data, clustered standard errors are already correcting for heteroskedasticity. Actually, I have run such a regression and detected heteroskedasticity. Since I used the pooled OLS model I have to cluster the standard errors anyway. Hence, I was hoping that I can address both issues simultaneously.  Is that right?

Comment: I think so, yes, but you might want to provide more detail on how you're handling the clustering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering you question: Cluster Robust is also Heteroskedastic Consistent.

I would recommend that you read the [A Practitioner's Guide to Cluster-Robust Inference](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_Cluster_Robust_October152013.pdf) which is a nice piece from Colin Cameron on several aspects of clustered/heteroskedastic robust errors.

Page 20 onward should help you out.

Comment: However, what happens if I correct for heteroscedasticity by means of clustered standard errors, even though there is prove that the initial results are homoscedastic. Is that a severe problem?

Comment: If the errors are homoscedastic, Heteroskedastic consistent errors are biased. Jusha Angrist and Jorn Pischke have a nice discussion around that topic in the book Mostly Harmless Econometrics (Chapter 8)